# Custom certificate/key pair does not work on OpenVPN clients

Tags: windows, unix, openvpn, certificate, keys

I have setup very basic OpenVPN network on Windows Server 2008. My clients are IP Cameras having Unix OS and built-in feature of openVPN connectivity. Initially I used a common client certificate/key pair for all cameras and that worked fine with `duplicate-cn` Enabled.

Now I am trying to create custom client certificate/key pair with unique `common names`. I used [this link](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#pki) to create custom certificate/keys for server and clients. After disabling the `duplicate-cn` on server, when I put client side certificate/key on camera, it just disappears. Camera remains no more available on LAN or openVPN. Even it does not bootup properly and I have to factory reset it to get it back to life with default settings.

I have double checked that I am following the steps mentioned in referenced openVPN link for Windows. Also all the mentioned files are placed properly on server and client. My server and client side configurations are as follows:

**Server**

```
;local a.b.c.d
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem
server 100.86.0.0 255.255.0.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt 3600
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-remote-ip
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log 5
verb 3
port 1194
management localhost 25333
```

**client**

```
dev tun
proto tcp
remote my.ovpnserver.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Comment: Just a though, but have you tried installing the OpenVPN client on some computer with a console, and then using that client config/keys?  It would be easier to debug from a computer with a console.  Once you have it working, then move it back to the cameras.

Comment: Is this (http://www.zac-ware.com/Configuring_OpenVPN_clients/OpenVPN_setup_guide_-_Windows#Step_2) what you are referring me to setup? If yes, then I am trying to set it up on my Win8 PC but it is asking for .NET framework 3.5 or higher where as Win8 already has 4.5 installed. Can't proceed with installation, any help ?